# Additional layer to handle ajax calls better

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

my system works like below;

StatisticService

There is only http calls in my service layer and collect data to use in controller.

```
angular.module('app').factory('StatisticService', ['$http', 'CONFIG', function ($http, CONFIG) {

var urlBase = CONFIG.API_END_POINT + '/statistics';

return  {
    getReport : function (data) {
        return $http.post( CONFIG.API_END_POINT + '/reports/mainReport', data);
    }
}
}]);
```

StatisticController

```
function init() {
        var mediaAccounts = MediaAccountService.findAll(),
            searchQueryList = SearchQueryService.getAll(),
            tags = TagService.getAllActiveTags(),
            dates = $scope.CacheService.getData('dateFormats');

        $q.all([mediaAccounts, searchQueryList, tags, dates])
            .then(function (result) {
                $scope.mediaAccounts.push.apply($scope.mediaAccounts, result[0].data.resultData);
                $scope.searchQueryList = result[1].data.resultData;
                $scope.tags = result[2].data.resultData;
                $scope.dateFilter = result[3];
                $scope.dateFilter.selected = $scope.dateFilter[1];
            }).then(function () {
            $scope.refreshChart();
        });
    }
```

There is an init function for get methods and fill my controller with static data after that ive many post methods like;

```
function getReport(type) {
        return StatisticService.getReport({
            statisticType: type,
            dateFormat: $scope.dateFilter.selected,
            startDate: $scope.date.startDate.output('time'),
            endDate: $scope.date.endDate.output('time'),
            tagList: $scope.query.tagList,
            searchQueryList: $scope.query.searchQueryList,
            userIdList: $scope.query.userIdList
        });
    }
```

And this method checks success and error promises. Now i need to find a new approach to handle my calls against an unexcepted errors or if error occurs on front end it should not reach to rest services.

Comment: have a look at http interceptors

Comment: im doing like this way. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[$Http Interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) - For purposes of global error handling, authentication, or any kind of synchronous or asynchronous pre-processing of request or postprocessing of responses, it is desirable to be able to intercept requests before they are handed to the server and responses before they are handed over to the application code that initiated these requests. The interceptors leverage the promise APIs to fulfill this need for both synchronous and asynchronous pre-processing.

From Angular docs:

```
// register the interceptor as a service
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {
    // optional method
    'request': function(config) {
      // do something on success
      return config;
    },

    // optional method
   'requestError': function(rejection) {
      // do something on error
      if (canRecover(rejection)) {
        return responseOrNewPromise
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    },



    // optional method
    'response': function(response) {
      // do something on success
      return response;
    },

    // optional method
   'responseError': function(rejection) {
      // do something on error
      if (canRecover(rejection)) {
        return responseOrNewPromise
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
});

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```